# Changing y axis names in grc1leg stata

Tags: graph, stata

I combined two graphs using grc1leg. I want to be able to change y-axis names for each individual graph. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Specify the `ytitle` for each graph before combining with `grc1leg`

```
sysuse auto, clear

scatter mpg price, name(A) ytitle("Apples")
scatter weight price, name(B) ytitle("Bananas")

grc1leg A B
```

Comment: I'm creating graphs with a loop within each loop I have the ugly y variable names. I need to edit them

Comment: You might have better luck receiving a useful answer if you post a data example and some code that you've written so far.

Comment: @Cybernike is correct here. There will be an easy solution, which might be (for example) picking up the variable labels rather than the variable names as part of your loop. But otherwise this is too close to "My graphs are not what I want, so how do I fix that?".